# ZipFile.CreateEntryFromFile File is stored with extension, but want to add extension when zipped

Tags: c#, zip

My class currently adds documents to zip folder via

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create)) {
    foreach (var filePath in files) {
        if (File.Exists(filePath.Value)) {
            zip.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath.Value, filePath.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

`files` is a `Dictionary`, the `Value` is a file path without file extensions, as they are stored on the server without extensions (lets assume they are all .pdfs)

Is there a way I can add .pdf to the files as they are stored in zip? So that when the zip folder is extracted, the files have extensions?

Note: My assumption is that if I simply add .pdf to `filePath`, it won't be a valid path when trying to `CreateEntryFromFile`

Comment: Save it to a temporary file with the extension and then zip that up and delete it when done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that [`CreateEntryFromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx) has separate parameters for the filename and the entry name, I'd expect you to just be able to modify the second argument:

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    foreach (var filePath in files)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath.Value))
        {
            // Note the second argument
            zip.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath.Value, filePath.Key + ".pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, change whatever code is building the dictionary in the first place to include the extension in the dictionary key. (This may or may not be appropriate based on what else you use the dictionary for, or whether you even really need a dictionary.)

Comment: Will have to test that, seems logical

Comment: You are correct, the 2nd argument is in fact the name of the file as stored within the zip folder. Thanks a lot